# Have child elements divide equally among parent height

Tags: html, css

I know you can have an element's children divide the parent's width equally so that each element has the same width and fills the parent's width entire with the following:

```
#parent {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.child {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**However, I was wondering if there was a way to divide the *height* equally among the children.** I searched Google and tried to find it out myself but came up with nothing.

Javascript and jQuery are OK to use, and pretty much any other library if necessary.

**EDIT:** The number of children is not known.

**EDIT 2:** I found my own solution with jQuery (children have class `item`):

```
$(".item").css("height", (100 /  $(".item").length) + "%");
```

It seems to work in the same way as the flexible box model described below.

Comment: How many children? % height with parent `position:relative` seems like the way to go here.

Comment: @spender The number of children isn't known. It can be any number. Edited question to state this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Flexible box model ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex))

The nicest solution is a solution that does **not** work in IE 10-.

So how does this work, taking the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

You would do (see below for explanation)

```
#container{
     display: flex; /* add -webkit and -ms prefixes yourself */
     flex-direction: column;
}
.box{
     flex-grow: 1;
}
```

So, I am not even going to get into a full explanation of how flex boxes work, but to explain this code. `display:flex` sets the container to order it's children as flex boxes. Next `flex-direction: column` makes it work horizontally rather than vertically and the `flex-grow: 1` makes all children equal size. If one would have `flex-grow:2` the children would be arranged as such that one of them would be twice as big as the others.

## Alternative way

The alternative way which will work in any browser is of course by counting the elements when outputting your code and simply setting an inline `style="height: n%"` or if for some reason you're absolutely bound by client side code only you can always just count the number of elements and then set the height (giving something along the lines of `$(".box").css("height", Math.floor( 1 / $(".box").length * 100) + " px" )`).

Comment: I like flex boxes, but they're a massive PITA to get right on all browsers because of the different revisions of the implementation. http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Comment: @spender: I know, I know :'( Still, it's been getting a lot better and with all browsers except IE updating quite forcefully it seems quite usable nowadays.

Comment: f*&^!ng  IE still making our lives difficult!

Comment: @spender: True that, like the other one causing trouble is the Android Browser, but since I discovered intel crosswalk project I am now only bashing on IE again :P

Comment: @spender: It's just an 'alternative' to phonegap (well, technically it's not, but whatever). For me however it meant that I could develop my cross platform applications without stressing half as much :P

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="main" style="height:100%; background:yellow;">
<div ></div>
<div ></div>
<div ></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("main");
var y = x.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
var z = 100/(y.length);
for (i=0; i<y.length; i++)
{
y[i].style.height = z + "%";
}
</script>
```